# Error handling in Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm making a basic port scanner.
I'm trying to print "closed" when I connect to a closed
port and "open" when I connect to an open port.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
(condition-case (tcp-connect (list-ref host 0) port)
    [(exn) (print "closed")]
    ['nil (print "open")]))
```

My open isn't printing correctly when it should (have tested with netcat).
How I understand condition-case is it matches errors. I'm trying to handle the case of no errors i.e. connection is successful.

Is there a better approach to this? I feel that I'm over thinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being familiar with Chicken I would expect something like this to be what you want:

```
(condition-case 
    (begin (tcp-connect (list-ref host 0) port)
           (print "open"))
    [(exn) (print "closed")])
```

That is, the expression given to `condition-case` is the "happy path" (like a try block in Java).